# How to change jasperserver login page to automatically direct you to a specified URL

Tags: jasperserver

Currently my Jasperserver login page looks like this [jasperLoginExample](http://docs.treasure-data.com/images/jasperserver-login.png)

I am using CAS to Login so the Jasperserver login no longer works

All I need to do is change the jasperserver login so that when it is loaded it will automatically redirect the user to "https://cas.nwu:8443/cas-server-webapp"

NOTE:

I am using jasperserver-pro 5.0.1